# Can I get the firewall's status by c# code?

Tags: c#

Can I get the firewall's status by c# code?
I want to inform the user when his firewall blocked

Comment: Do you mean Windows' built-in Firewall, or just any firewall? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @horsedrowner: any Windows Firewall has to export its status trough WMI, otherwise the Security Center would show the "red shield".

Comment: something similar [Check for Third Party Firewalls on a Machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615203/check-for-third-party-firewalls-on-a-machine)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following links to interact with Windows firewall. Include NetFwTypeLib as a reference to your project.

For Window Firewall you can create the manager with the following code:

```
Type NetFwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", false);
```

`INetFwMgr manager= (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType);`

from there you can read about the various methods to configure with windows firewall.

Windows Firewall (Windows XP...limited Vista and 7 support)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366452(v=VS.85).aspx

Windows Firewall with advanced security (Windows Vista/7)

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366459(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks,
You've been very helpful

Answer (score 1):

On a Windows 7 machine this is what I do in order to detect whether or not the machine has the Windows Firewall enabled. I take the same approach as Dylan suggested.

Just remember to add a reference to `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common`.

```
Type NetFwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", false);
INetFwMgr mgr = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType);
bool firewallEnabled = mgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.FirewallEnabled;
```

I would like to see a WMI solution of this task, but this has worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 3 labels, this will show the status of all of the firewalls in a form Application.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
private string getFirewallStatus()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;


        Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);


        if (process != null)
        {
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("netsh advfirewall show allprofiles | find \"State\"");
            process.StandardInput.Close();
            string outputString = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < outputString.Length - 3; i++)
            {
                if (outputString.Substring(i, 3).CompareTo(@"OFF") == 0)
                {
                    count++;
                    switch (count)
                    {
                        case 1: label16.Text = "Off"; label16.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green; break;
                        case 2: label17.Text = "Off"; label17.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green; break;
                        case 3: label18.Text = "Off"; label18.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green; break;
                        default: MessageBox.Show("Firewall status unable to be found!"); break;
                    }
                }
                else if (outputString.Substring(i, 2).CompareTo("ON") == 0)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            count = 0;
            return outputString;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use Windows Security Center APIs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wscapi/

```
    [DllImport("wscapi.dll")]
    private static extern int WscGetSecurityProviderHealth(int inValue, ref int outValue);

    var outValue = -1;
    var commandResultCode = WscGetSecurityProviderHealth(1, ref outValue);
    if (commandResultCode > 0)
    {
        return outValue == 0;
    }
```