# Check for Third Party Firewalls on a Machine

Tags: c#, security, wmi, firewall, windows-server-2008-r2

I am working on doing a check for Firewalls.  The following code quite easily checks the status of the default Windows Firewall:

```
    INetFwMgr manager = GetFireWallManager();
    bool isFirewallEnabled = manager.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.FirewallEnabled;
    if (isFirewallEnabled == false)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Firewall is not enabled.");
    }
    else
    {
      Consoe.WriteLine("Firewall is enabled.");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

   private static INetFwMgr GetFireWallManager()
   {
     Type objectType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid(firewallGuid));
     return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType) as INetFwMgr;
   }
```

The question then becomes: How do I find the status of a non-Windows Firewall?
If the Firewall is properly integrated, will the above check work just the same or is there a better method for doing this?
I have checked this post: [C# Windows Security Center Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493170/c-sharp-windows-security-center-settings) and this post: [C# - How to chceck if external firewall is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975321/c-sharp-how-to-chceck-if-external-firewall-is-enabled) but both proved relatively unhelpful.

I have been looking into the WMI API but it is pretty confusing so far, and the documentation via MSDN hasn't been too promising.
I have also tried messing around with [SelectQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.selectquery.aspx) but so far I have been unsuccessful.
Can anyone assist me in a new starting point or to where I might be able to find better documentation/instructions concerning 3rd Party Firewalls?

**EDIT:** Currently I am exploring further into WMI, specifically the class `FirewallProduct` as suggested by a post.

**UPDATE 2:** I have been testing the following snippet:

```
  string wmiNameSpace = "SecurityCenter2";
  ManagementScope scope;
  scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\{1}", "localhost", wmiNameSpace), null);
  scope.Connect();
  ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM FirewallProduct");
  ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
```

But running this results in the following error:
`Exception Invalid namespace`  and it points to line 39 (`scope.Connect()`).  I would not be at all surprised if I have simply missed a parameter or formatted something improperly, I just don't know what it is.

**UPDATE 3**  Switching from `SecurityCenter2` to `SecurityCenter` still yields the same `invalid namespace` error.

**UPDATE 4**  I moved the console app over to a different box (win7 not winserver08r2) and it properly reported back as expected.  So it may be an issue with the VM that I currently have been testing on.  Next step is to parse out active/inactive status

**UPDATE 5**  It was tested on another Server08 box and the same `invalid namespace` error appears.  Using `SecurityCenter` instead of `SecurityCenter2` does not resolve the issue.  Is there some underlying security feature Windows Server OS's use to prevent tampering with Firewalls, or do Server OS's not come with a specific key set of WMI features?

Comment: You may want to explore this page http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37714/Software-Development-Build-your-own-Windows-Securi

The three reference links at bottom also point to some useful pages.

Comment: The `SecurityCenter2` namespace is for Windows Vista, 7 and 8 , for XP you must use the `SecurityCenter` namespace.

Comment: @wjhguitarman - Why do you need to detect if a firewall is installed?

Comment: @Ramhound  It is part of a health analyzer that checks settings and statistics on a client's box.  Our software needs to have at least an exception turned on for it, so reporting what type of firewall is active can be helpful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> According to Microsoft **Q: How does Windows
> Security Center detect third-party products and their status?**
>
> A:
> Windows Security Center uses a two-tiered approach for detection
> status. One tier is manual, and the other tier is automatic through
> Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI). In manual detection mode,
> Windows Security Center searches for registry keys and files that are
> provided to Microsoft by independent software manufacturers. These
> registry keys and files let Windows Security Center detect the status
> of independent software. In WMI mode, software manufacturers determine
> their own product status and report that status back to Windows
> Security Center through a WMI provider. In both modes, Windows
> Security Center tries to determine whether the following is true:
>
> - An antivirus program is present.
> - The antivirus signatures are up-to-date.
> - Real-time scanning or on-access scanning is turned on for antivirus programs.
> - For firewalls, Windows Security Center
>   detects whether a third-party firewall is installed and whether the
>   firewall is turned on or not.

So you can use the WMI to determine if a third-party firewall is installed, using the `FirewallProduct` class, sometime ago I wrote an article about this topic which explain how obtain this info using the WMI.

- [`Getting the installed Antivirus, AntiSpyware and Firewall software using Delphi and the WMI`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/02/18/getting-the-installed-antivirus-antispyware-and-firewall-software-using-delphi-and-the-wmi/).

Try this sample C# to get the current Third-party firewall name and state installed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    class Program
    {
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                //select the proper wmi namespace depending of the windows version
                string WMINameSpace = System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5 ? "SecurityCenter2" : "SecurityCenter";
 
                ManagementScope Scope;
                Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\{1}", "localhost", WMINameSpace), null);

                Scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM FirewallProduct");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

                foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Firewall Name",WmiObject["displayName"]);                      
                    if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6) //is XP ?
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Enabled",WmiObject["enabled"]);    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","State",WmiObject["productState"]); 
                    }   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}",e.Message,e.StackTrace));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow you certainly seem to know your stuff!  I am in the middle of testing out your example but in the interest of not just copy-pasting I have a question, what is the "{0,-35} {1,-40}" in the `Console.WriteLine`and what is its purpose?

Comment: @wjhguitarman those are just formatting options so that it shows up nicely.

Comment: I read more on your blog link that you posted, and I should have much sooner, this whole time I have been attempting to get it working on Server 2008, not knowing it is only for desktop editions :(